# Type of periodicity in champernowne constant.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, periodic-functions

Digits of Champernowne  constant are aperiodic, else it will be rational. Fine! But it is not random because I can write a program which will give me the position of every digit. E.g. I can calculate the position of all zeroes. I sense a certain kind of periodicity here. Is there any mathematical terminology for such a kind of repetition?

Comment: So, where is the billionth zero? $${}$$ One could say this decimal has "low complexity".

Answer (score 1):

In algorithmic information theory the measure of how tersely a number (or string) can be described by a computer program is known as [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).

So in the sense you describe, Champernowne's constant would be considered to have low program-size complexity, to be highly compressible and hence not "random."